# PHP flush not printing output when called

Tags: php, pthreads

I want to echo some output before and after some pause.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php
class AsyncOperation extends Thread {

  public function __construct(){

  }

  public function run(){
    sleep(11);
echo "Running "; 

  }
 }
 echo "Its Here";

 flush();


 $thread = new AsyncOperation();

 $thread->start();

?>
```

This should show output "Its Here" ....and after 11 seconds ... should show "Running"

but the browser shows it like "Running Its Here", and shows the whole string after 11 seconds.

I don't know why this is happening . Please help me solve this problem I have been struck here for last 2 nights.

Any Solution ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need Output Buffering...!

I am not sure this works on all browsers, However this works perfectly on

- Google's Chrome.
- Mozilla FireFox
- Internet Explorer
- Opera

---

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
class AsyncOperation
{
    public function run()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            echo "                   ";
            echo str_pad('', 4096) . "\n";
            # Flushing out..........!
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        echo "Running ";
    }
}

echo "Its Here<br>";
$thread = new AsyncOperation();
$thread->run();
?>
```

I modified your `run()` with `sleep(1)` under a `for` loop which is same as `sleep(11)`.

Comment: this is strange, why we should use loops 10 time to make script execution sleep for 11 seconds. why we cannot use sleep(11) only. however, this is the only way works for me +1

Comment: Yeah a certain amount of content length has to be sent to the browser only then it gets flushed. That is why I am doing the `str_pad`